# What does "evidenced" mean in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

> O Henry did catch the color and movement of the city and evidenced a genuine sympathy for ordinary people.

Can you rephrase this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidenced in this sentence means "displayed" or "showed" in a way that can be seen by an observer.

"O Henry did catch the color and movement of the city and someone watching him could see he had a genuine sympathy for ordinary people."

Comment: Or *exhibited*. :)

Comment: Or most likely, *evidenced* is an error for *evinced*.